# Publish jrxml from Jaspersoft Studio to JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I have created new report in *Jaspersoft Studio* with Domain as Datasource and two Parameters `date_from and date_to (Timestamp)` to customize the report with condition `column_date IN BETWEEN date_from AND Date _to`. Based on parameter values works fine in studio preview.

But after publish the report into *JasperReports Server* with same Domain Datasource and same Input Control parameters it showing the error like **The report is empty.**

Steps I followed:

- Tested the Domain Datasource in *JR Server* (Connected)
- Created the Input control with same parameter name and same datatype in *JR Server*
- While running the report, Input control in shown and gave valid data

The result is report is empty, (but I have data in that date range)

Any help